# How can I order 2 mysql columns as 1

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I need some help with a query in mysql, I´ve been struggling for days with this and the more I research the more confused I get. Here is my query:

```
SELECT name, pax, agency, origin, destination, internal_notes,
       departure_flight, departure_date, arrival_date, arrival_flight,
       TIME_FORMAT(arrival_time, '%H:%i') AS arrival_time,
       TIME_FORMAT(pick_up, '%H:%i') AS pick_up, service_type
FROM reservas
WHERE arrival_date=? OR departure_date=?
ORDER BY pick_up, arrival_time ASC
```

from this query i select all my services from a certain date through a "while" that selects the service time depending on the service_type field on the DB so if its an arrival it selects arrival_time, if its a DEPARTURE or an INTERHOTEL it selects pick_up instead of arrival_time, the thing is that i need to order this results chronological no matter what kind of service they are, the result i get with the query above is the following:

EXAMPLE

```
ARRIVAL 13:10
ARRIVAL 13:15
ARRIVAL 13:40
DEPARTURE 13:05
DEPARTURE 13:45
INTERHOTEL 13:00
```

HOWEVER, what i need is to "mix" all the results and order them like this:

```
INTERHOTEL 13:00
DEPARTURE 13:05
ARRIVAL 13:10
ARRIVAL 13:15
ARRIVAL 13:40
DEPARTURE 13:45
```

Comment: Your results do not match the query.  There are, for instance, way more columns in the `SELECT`.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's because i got other data that i need to get from the DB, besides ordering the pick_up and arrival_time columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `CASE` expression:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN service_type IN ('DEPARTURE', 'INTERHOTEL') THEN pick_up ELSE arrival_time END) ASC
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon, this practically solved my whole problem, the only thing im having problems with is the same code on another script, it sorts all the results except for the first result, the code i used (with your help) is the following
` ORDER BY (CASE 
    WHEN service_type='ROUND TRIP' AND arrival_date=".$operation_date." THEN arrival_time
    WHEN service_type='DEPARTURE' THEN pick_up
    WHEN service_type='ONE WAY' THEN arrival_time
    WHEN service_type='INTERHOTEL' THEN pick_up
    ELSE pick_up
    END) ASC`

Comment: @FernandoDlp . . . You may want to ask another question . . . including sample data, desired results, and your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t you just want to remove the pick_up from your ORDER BY?

So just make it `ORDER BY arrival_time ASC`

Comment: No, because if the service is DEPARTURE i need the pick_up row